# unexpected behavior while appending chars using strcat

Tags: c++, string, strcat

```
char buf[256];
char c48 = (char) 48;
char c49 = (char) 49;
char c50 = (char) 50;
char c51 = (char) 51;
char c52 = (char) 52;
char c53 = (char) 53;
strcpy(buf, &c48);
strcat(buf, &c49);
strcat(buf, &c50);
strcat(buf, &c51);
strcat(buf, &c52);
strcat(buf, &c53);
puts(buf);
```

I expected to output string to be 012345
However when i did a cout this is the result 010210321043210543210.
I don't understand why this happens. Could it be that the buf gets copied using the strcat method? Sorry for this basic question. I come fron java background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy(buf, &c48);
```

The second parameter is not a pointer to a NUL-terminated string. This line, and all lines after it, exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: I see therefore strcat/cpy needs to work with char* terminated by a '\0' is that what u mean